# Hide image comes from ng-repeat in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am not able to hide image.

I am fetching the image details from database and showing them in grid format. Here is the code:

```
<div ng-repeat="imageUrl in images" class="col-xs-3 img-wrap">

  <span class="close" id="close">&times;</span>
  <div class="my-gallery" itemscope id="grid"   >

    <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" >

    <a href="{{imageUrl}}" id="thumb" name="{{pid[$index]}}" class="thumbnail " itemprop="contentUrl"  data-id="{{pid[$index]}}" data-size="800x600"> 
    <img src="" class="img-responsive " data-id="{{pid[$index]}}" id="{{pid[$index]}}" ng-src="{{thumb[$index]}}" style="min-height:50px;height:50px;">
    </a>

    </figure>

</div>
</div>
```

and here is more code:

```
$scope.myFunc = function(btnId) {
        alert(btnId);
document.getElementById(btnId).style.visibility = "visible";
    
};
```

I want to hide the respective image. There could be multiple image but image id is different. So, what I want is when user click on any image it will hide.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all Don't use **`getElementById`**.In angular you can simple bind the **`$scope`** variable.

Have a variable with the image object to **`show/hide`**. Make it true or false when you need to **`show/not`**.

On **`ng-click`** you can set the variable to be `false`. bind the variable to the element, so that you can hide whenever necessary.

```
<div ng-if="img.show">
 <img src="" class="img-responsive " data-id="{{pid[$index]}}" id="{{pid[$index]}}" ng-src="{{thumb[$index]}}" style="min-height:50px;height:50px;">
    </a>
</div>
```

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module('webapp', [])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.data =  [
   {
    "id": 5454554,
    "Url":        "https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3261/2801924702_ffbdeda927_d.jpg",
     "show":true
      },
         {
    "id": 5454554,
    "Url":        "https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3261/2801924702_ffbdeda927_d.jpg",
     "show":true
      }
    ];
  $scope.hide = function(img){
    img.show = false;
  }
 
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="webapp">
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
 <div class="add-pic-box1 col-md-3">
    <div ng-repeat="img in data" >     
      <div ng-if="img.show">
    <img class="thumb" ng-model="add_new_ads_mdl.img_add" imgid = "{{img._id}}" src="{{img.Url}}" />
      <button ng-click="hide(img)"> HIDE ME </button>
        </div >     
   </div>
     
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for answer but what do i need to add in function(btnId){. i am learning angular. sorry for asking silly things. voted up.

Comment: @CalculatingMachine check the demo, i have added a function on the click of button

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-click with $event

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <a href="#" ng-click="removeMe($event)">Click me</a>
</div>

app.controller("Ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.removeMe = function(event) {
    event.toElement.remove()
  };
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/grishkovelli/3edwbf04/)